# How to make product catalog paging visible to SE crawlers if it is done using SELECT and JS?

Tags: select, paging, catalog

I have a product catalog site. Each category of products has many pages. Paging is done using SELECT tag with onChange event. It calls JS function which manipulates current URL and sets window.location. It takes into account current use settings, filter settings, etc.

I doubt that search engines will process all this javascript and see the resulting URL to go there and index another page of this category.

I can generate on server side a list of URL for all pages but how to put it into html so it will not be visible to user but visible to crawlers?

I can put it the list into a div with display:none but will be be indexed? Will be be considered cloaking?